# how use hyper v and simulator together on windows 10

Tags: virtual-machine, simulator, hyper-v

I work with docker in my system and now I need to use **Nox simulator** but when I open the simulator error to me that Hyper-v must disabled!

[image: Error Image]

How can i use NoxPlayer and Hyper-v together

Comment: They have a Hyper-V compatible version in beta https://support.bignox.com/ja/else/hypervonbeta but it's much slower, you're better off using Bluestacks

Comment: I checked Bluestacks but it also want to disable Hyper-V @Martheen !!!

Comment: you must run it as admin https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412148150157-How-to-enable-Hyper-V-on-Windows-for-BlueStacks-5, It works fine right now in my Windows 11 with WSL and Hyper-V enabled